Mockall invoke input FnMut argument
I have a trait like such:
#[cfg_attr(test, automock)]
trait Foo {
    #[cfg_attr(test, concretize)]
    fn for_each<F>(&self, processor: F)
    where
        Self: Sized,
        F: FnMut(&u32);
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct UnderTest;

impl UnderTest {
   fn do_something<F: Foo>(&self, foo: &F) {
     foo.for_each(|x| {
         eprintln!("Invoked with {x}");
     })
   }
}

In my test I want to do something like:
#[cfg(test)]
fn do_something() {
   let mut foo = MockFoo::new();
   foo.expect_for_each().times(1).returning(|cb| {
     cb(&0);
     cb(&1);
   });

   let t = UnderTest::default();
   t.do_something(&foo);
}

The problem is that when I compile this, there's an error because the returning closure receives a &FnMut instead of a &mut FnMut so there's no way to invoke it. Am I missing something obvious or is it impossible to actually mock this situation?
expected closure signature `for<'a> fn(&'a (dyn for<'a> std::ops::FnMut(&'a u32))) -> _`
   found closure signature `for<'a> fn(&'a mut (dyn for<'a> std::ops::FnMut(&'a u32))) -> _`


The code you're showing doesn't make a great deal of sense.  For a start, the Self: Sized bound on Foo::for_each makes the method non-dispatchable from Foo trait objects, so the call to foo.for_each in UnderTest::do_something is impossible; removing that bound does not help because generic methods are not object-safe; making the method non-generic (e.g. by changing the processor parameter from being generic F to fn(&u32)) then compiles and the test runs without generating the error you have shown.  Please edit your question to provide a [mre].

I'm not asking that it be dispatchable from Foo trait objects. In all cases I have a specific instance of Foo via generics. I'm not sure what other minimal reproducible example I can provide since you're basically saying "if you change the parameters of the problem it's not a problem". It looks to be a problem with concretize - the only workaround I've found is to remove it and make F: 'static, but that has all sorts of annoying consequences. I can't link to a playground link because mockall isn't on playground.

I see in my UnderTest I reference &Foo - is that what you meant? It should be a generic over Foo instead of &Foo which isn't a thing & would need to be &dyn Foo.

Yes, I was thrown by the &Foo (which absolutely is a thing: prior to Rust 2018 edition the dyn keyword didn't exist and trait objects were described in that way; it then became a soft error and in the 2021 edition that became a hard error).

As documented for concretize:


It can’t be used on methods with a closure argument (though this may be fixable).


I think you might instead have to use the mock! macro to create your own mock object, but you must also add a F: 'static constraint:
trait Foo {
    fn for_each<F>(&self, processor: F)
    where
        Self: Sized,
        F: 'static + FnMut(&u32);
}

#[cfg(test)]
mockall::mock! {
    Bar {}
    impl Foo for Bar {
        fn for_each<F>(&self, processor: F)
        where
            Self: Sized,
            F: 'static + FnMut(&u32);
    }
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct UnderTest;

impl UnderTest {
    fn do_something<F: Foo>(&self, foo: &F) {
        foo.for_each(|x| {
            eprintln!("Invoked with {0}", x);
        })
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
fn do_something() {
    let mut foo = MockBar::new();
    foo.expect_for_each()
        .times(1)
        .returning(|mut cb| {
            cb(&0);
            cb(&1);
        });
    let t = UnderTest::default();
    t.do_something(&foo);
}

If that's not acceptable to you, one possible workaround could be to add a lifetime parameter to the trait and constrain F to that, then within the mock! invocation implement the trait only with 'static lifetime parameter for your mock object:
trait Foo<'a> {
    fn for_each<F>(&self, processor: F)
    where
        Self: Sized,
        F: 'a + FnMut(&u32);
}

#[cfg(test)]
mockall::mock! {
    Bar {}
    impl Foo<'static> for Bar {
        fn for_each<F>(&self, processor: F)
        where
            Self: Sized,
            F: 'static + FnMut(&u32);
    }
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct UnderTest;

impl UnderTest {
    fn do_something<'a, F: Foo<'a>>(&self, foo: &F) {
        foo.for_each(|x| {
            eprintln!("Invoked with {0}", x);
        })
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
fn do_something() {
    let mut foo = MockBar::new();
    foo.expect_for_each()
        .times(1)
        .returning(|mut cb| {
            cb(&0);
            cb(&1);
        });
    let t = UnderTest::default();
    t.do_something(&foo);
}


It's unfortunate that you have to change the origin trait to conform to details of the mocking library but thanks for the detailed example!

Also, it may be a bug with concretize as per https://github.com/asomers/mockall/issues/577
